# How to dynamically allocate memory on andress whom I point to?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, allocation

Hell'o
I want to create my own dynamic array (vector) class, but don't know how to allocate memory on addres whom I point to. In function add I added line like: 
`int * object = new (this->beginning + this->lenght) int (paramValue);` But visual studio shows me an error message "operator new cannot be called with the given arguments". How to make it works, which arguments should I send to the *new* operator?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And when you edit your question with that code, then also please include the complete and full error message without any editing.

Comment: what's wrong with `int* object = new int[length];`? I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You basically just want to look how your compiler's `std::vector` does it, and do it exactly like that. Or you go one step further and use `std::vector` instead of copying it :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't allocate any memory. With placement new you create an object in memory that must already be allocated to your program.

Comment: On a desktop user privilege addresses are virtual. There is some extra effort to access physical addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(I am not sure to understand your question, but....)</sup>

You might want to use the [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) operator (but to implement a `<vector>` like thing you don't need that). Then you'll need to `#include <new>`

But you probably don't need that. Just call plain `new` from your constructor, and plain `delete` from your destructor. Something like `int*arr = new int[length];` (in constructor) and later `delete[] arr;` (in destructor).

<sup>(it looks that you are misunderstanding something; I recommend spending several days reading a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book)</sup>

Comment: I strongly believe you should not need it.

Comment: On a desktop user privilege addresses are virtual.  There is some extra effort to access physical addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> how to allocate memory on address whom I point to

Insufficient information -- what kind of system? custom hardware? OS?

---

On a desktop, you could use 2 steps.  You allocate a block of bytes using something like:

```
uint8_t* myMemoryBlock = new uint8_t[1000];  // 1000 byte block
```

Then you might contemplate using placement new at the address "you point to" using 'myMemoryBlock', with a cast.

On a desktop, the dynamic memory system can be used this way...

But if you are planning to create a user defined type any way, just new that type, and let the dynamic memory fall where it may, as opposed to positioning it on myMemoryBlock.

On a desktop, there is (generally) no memory your user-privilege level executable can access with 'new'.  All other memory is protected.

mmap on Linux maps devices or files into your executables memory range.  I am unfamiliar with such devices, but I have used mmap with files.

---

update  2017/03/19

Note 1 - user-privilege level tasks are typically blocked from accessing other / special memory.

Note 2 - memory addresses, such as 'myMemoryBlock' above, are virtual, not physical.  This includes code addresses, automatic memory addresses, dynamic memory addresses.  If your processor has memory management hardware support, your coding has special efforts to access physical addresses, in memory or otherwise.

---

On a single-board-computer (SBC), (with or without an OS) I would expect that the address you wish to 'allocate' will not be within the 'dynamic' memory set up by the board support package (BSP).

On this kind of embedded system (on a SBC), someone (an architect) has 'mapped' this 'special' memory to an address range not in use for other purposes (i.e. not part of dynamic memory).  Here, you simply find out what the address is, and use it by casting the uintXX_t value to a pointer of appropriate type.  Something like:

```
myDataType* p = reinterpret_cast<myDataType*>(premappedAddress);
```

For more info, you should seek out other sites discussing embedded systems.

---